# Can I separate socket.io event listeners into different modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I'm handling over 15 different socket events, I'd like to manage certain socket.io events within the modules that are related to those events.

For example, I'd like to have a file named login.js handle the `login` socket event, and a file named register.js handle the registration socket event.

index.js:

```
socket.on("connection", function (client) {

    console.log("Client connected to socket!");

    client.on("login", function (data) {

        validate(data){

            socket.sockets.emit("login_success", data);

        }

    });

    client.on("register", function (data) {

        register(data){

            socket.sockets.emit("register_success", data);

        }

    });

});
```

Is there a way that I can put `client.on("register", function (data) { ...` in one file and `client.on("login", function (data) { ...` in another?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I usually split various client related functionality (I usually call them handlers) into individual modules, and then `require` and use them in whatever file creates the socket.io connection.

Here is an example module, that exports a function which expects to be passed a socket.io client:

```
/* register-handler.js */
module.exports = function (client) {
  // registration related behaviour goes here...
  client.on('register', function (data) {
    // do stuff
  });
};
```

Which is consumed by a file that creates a new socket, listens for connections, and passes them to the handler, which then listens to events on the client.

```
/*  main.js */
// require your handlers
var handleRegister = require('./register-handler');

// .. set up socket.io

socket.on('connection', function (client) {
  // register handlers
  handleRegister(client);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way

```
socket.on("connection", function (client) {

    console.log("Client connected to socket!");

    require('./login')(socket, client);
    require('./register')(socket, client);
});
```

login.js

```
module.exports = function(socket, client) {
    client.on("login", function (data) {

        validate(data){

            socket.sockets.emit("login_success", data);

        }

    });
};
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer. The accepted one isn't wrong by any means. However, with this solution, you can simply require each module and it will handle its events without clogging up the "config" area. With things like CRUD through WebSocket, there can be 4+ sub-events for every event. And with the amount of different resources in a modern application, the previous solution could grow cumbersome very quickly.

Answer (score 2):

Create a listener folder, put all event handlers in separate files, and then with some tricks you can include all that listeners.

in listener/index.js :

```
 module.exports = (io) => {
 const fs = require('fs');
 const path = require('path');
 const listenersPath = path.resolve(__dirname);
 io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    fs.readdir(listenersPath, (err, files) => {
      if (err) {
        process.exit(1);
      }
      files.map((fileName) => {
        if (fileName !== 'index.js') {
          require(path.resolve(__dirname, fileName))(io, socket);
        }
      });
    });
  });
};
```

and then in different files, you can handle listeners.

listener/login.js:

```
  module.exports = (io, socket) => {
      socket.on('login', (data) => {
        // handle the event
      });
  }
```

in your app.js file:

```
const initListeners = require('./listeners/index');

const server = app.listen(3000);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
initListeners(io);
```

you can also do this for the event emitters.

Answer (score 1):

it is very simple

```
// export from your handler file:

exports.myHandler = socket => data => { // the socket object is available due to closure }

// import in your socket app.js file
 
import { myHandler } from './handlers/mySocketHandler'
 
// now just call the myHandler function.
// pass the socket object from the app.js file and it will return a handler function

socket.on('message', myHandler(socket))
```

Comment: This is working solution, but it needs further improvement to show the case of having payload from event like messageBody for example.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, using `exports` and `require`.

Check [this](http://openmymind.net/2012/2/3/Node-Require-and-Exports/) out.