# Listen in server to a socket emit by a client

Tags: node.js, angular, express, websocket, socket.io

I'm trying to learn socket.io in my Angular/Node app.

I would emit an event in angular side then listen to it in Back end.

In my **component** file :

```
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';
import { AjouttextService } from '../ajouttext.service';
import { DataSource } from "@angular/cdk/collections";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { nomchamp } from '../model';
import * as io from "socket.io-client";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-datatable',
  templateUrl: './datatable.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./datatable.component.css']
})
export class DatatableComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private dataService: AjouttextService) { }
  data = [];
  url = 'http://localhost:8080';
  private socket = io.connect(this.url);

  displayedColumns = ['text'];
  dataSource = new UserDataSource(this.dataService);
  ;

  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    filterValue = filterValue.trim(); // Remove whitespace
    filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase(); // MatTableDataSource defaults to lowercase matches
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.socket.emit('save-message', { room: "hello" });
  }
}
```

Emit event in Angular is set `OnInit` so it should emit an event in all cases and my component is called by app.component.

Then **In server** side I would print a console.log `on` `'save-message'` event

```
var http = require("http");
var admin = require('firebase-admin');
var firebase = require("firebase");
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var port = process.env.app_port || 8080; // set our port
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
var server = app.listen(port);
var io = require("socket.io")(server);
var routerProj = require("./routes/routes");
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT ,DELETE');

  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept,*");
  next();
});
var config = {
  ...Config...
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);


var serviceAccount = require("./ServiceAcountKey.json");
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://datatable-18f93.firebaseio.com"
});
app.use("/v1", routerProj, function (req) {
  //Create HTTP server and listen on port 8000 for requests


});
// Print URL for accessing server
console.log("Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8080/");
io.on("connection", function (socket) {
  console.log("user connected !");
});
io.on('save-message', function (socket) {
  console.log("user saved message");
});
```

When I run server only connection event is working. I get " user connected in my console but not " user saved message"

**What I expect  ?**

Print  `user saved message` on server console when client run app ( DatatableComponent component )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to modify your server side code to:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log('user connected !');
  socket.on('save-message', function (socket) {
    console.log('user saved message');
  });
});
```

Register message listener on `socket` object instead of `io` which is received upon initial connection.

Comment: Should I absolutely write my sockets in `connection` event ?
How can I use sockets in my routes file for example ?

Comment: You can split your handlers into different modules and then just require those handlers within `connection` event block. Check this out for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24815106/can-i-separate-socket-io-event-listeners-into-different-modules#24815411

Comment: So if I had understood I should wrap everything in `connection` socket

Comment: Yes, in your main file where you will establish single socket io connection. Inside, just use exported functions from different modules